# Custom buttons на разных API

Tags: android, button

Я создаю класс для создания квадратной кнопки, использую его в макете, но кнопки не показываются на версии Lollipop и marshmallow, только на Nougat. В чем может быть проблема? Код и скрины прилагаю.

Java:

```
public class SquareButton extends ToggleButton {

    public SquareButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int size = widthMeasureSpec > heightMeasureSpec ? heightMeasureSpec : widthMeasureSpec;
        super.onMeasure(size, size);

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="ru.energyhouse.energyhouse.presenter.Light.MainMenuLightFragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_icon_IV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline11"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/light_lightoff_big_ic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_icon_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/main_menu_light_icon_IV"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/main_menu_light_icon_IV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline11"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_scroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_menu_light_icon_TV"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_firstRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ru.energyhouse.energyhouse.model.SquareButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_bright_Btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/scenes_click"
                    android:paddingTop="45dp"
                    android:textOff="@null"
                    android:textOn="@null" />

                <ru.energyhouse.energyhouse.model.SquareButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_soft_Btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/scenes_click"
                    android:paddingTop="45dp"
                    android:textOff="@null"
                    android:textOn="@null" />

                <ru.energyhouse.energyhouse.model.SquareButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_manual_Btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/scenes_click"
                    android:paddingTop="45dp"
                    android:textOff="@null"
                    android:textOn="@null" />

                <ru.energyhouse.energyhouse.model.SquareButton
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/groups_click"
                    android:paddingTop="45dp"
                    android:textOff="@null"
                    android:textOn="@null" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_secondRow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ru.energyhouse.energyhouse.model.SquareButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_allOff_Btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/scenes_click"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@null"
                    android:textOff="@null"
                    android:textOn="@null" />

                <ru.energyhouse.energyhouse.model.SquareButton
                    android:id="@+id/main_menu_light_backLight_Btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/scenes_click"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@null"
                    android:textOff="@null"
                    android:textOn="@null" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Lollipop:

[image: Lollipop]

Nougat:

[image: Nougat]

background scenes_clock:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/square_button_background_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/square_button_background_def"/>
</selector>
```

**UPD.**
Проблема в контейнерах (не пойму в чем именно), т.к. вне контейнера всё рисуется.

Comment: Может проблема в бекграунде? Покажите код `scenes_click.xml` и всё, что с ним связано, если там селектор. Попробуйте поставить в качестве бекграунда простой цвет, будет ли работать.

Comment: @eugeneek Код добавил. устанавливал цвет - не работает.

Comment: @eugeneek только нуга почему то отображает. Маршмеллоу тоже не отображает.

Comment: А в Layout Inspector-е смотрели на проблемных версиях ОС? Думаю он вам поможет найти в чем же суть проблемы.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja мало чем мне помогло, если честно. Я примерно понимаю в чем дело, но выбраться из ямы не могу.

Comment: Так в чем дело-то? Тут только 2 варианта, либо неверный размер (расположение), либо бэкграунд (селектор). В инспекторе первый можно точно проверить.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja решил проблему. В `onMeasure()` указал размер кнопки в виде высоты его родителя.

Comment: Ок, значит с размером проблема была. Это как раз должно быть видно в Layout Inspector-е.